# Why are values greater than $\pi$ radians given as negative in exponential form?

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

> Find the fifth roots of $-3+3i$ in exponential form.

My answers are:
$$1.335e^{3i\pi/20}$$ 
$$1.335e^{11i\pi/20}$$
$$1.335e^{19i\pi/20}$$
$$1.335e^{27i\pi/20}$$
$$1.335e^{35i\pi/20}$$

Wolfram gives the last two  as $1.335e^{-13i\pi/20}$ and $1.335e^{-i\pi/4}$ ([link to Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(-3%20%2B%203i)%5E(1%2F5)))

> [image]

I can see these are my values minus $2\pi$, but why is it written like this, i.e. in negative form?

Comment: Your link is broken. But these represent the same values. The exponents are simply angles, which are identical modulo $2\pi$

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexArgument.html

Comment: its for the same reason we generally write for example $-1\mod 11$ and not $10\mod 11$, with $3\mod4$ an obvious exception. $|\theta|\le\pi$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha is using the **principal branch** of the complex logarithm ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Definition_of_principal_value)), which is defined to have complex part in $(-\pi,\pi]$; equivalently, it is using the **principal value** of the complex argument function ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Principal_value)).

Answer (score 3):

The polar form of a complex number is not unique. A common convention to choose a unique angle of a complex number is to return the angle in the range $-\pi < \theta \le \pi$. This is called the *principle argument* of the number, rather than just an argument of the number. But because you can go forward or backward one rotation about the origin and end up in the same spot, you have that you can add any multiple of $2\pi$ and still represent the same coordinate.

Algebraically, we have that $e^{2k\pi i} = 1$, so $r e^{i\theta} = r e^{i\theta}e^{2k\pi i} = r e^{i\theta + 2k \pi i}$ for any integer $k$.